# Getting filenames in the right alphanumerical order

Tags: bash, sorting, glob

I'm having trouble with this command (suspect it's bash related, and not program specific)

```
montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 -background '#ffffff' -fill 'gray' -auto-orient  -tile 8x6 -geometry 200x200+2+2 ./*.bluemap.jpg /media/
```

The problem is that it starts with the file 100002.bluemap.jpg, not the lowest  number which is 2016.bluemap.jpg

All numbers don't exist, for example the next after 2016 is 6438, 6685,9879

Is there anyway to get it to do the job correctly, the right order?

Or do I need to create some list or something?

I'm little lost..

Comment: Add names of your files and your desired order to your question (no comment, no link, no image).

Answer (score 2):

Sort the filenames using GNU `sort` and read the list into an array, then expand it in the `montage` invocation.

```
readarray -d '' -t files < <(printf '%s\0' ./*.bluemap.jpg | sort -z -t/ -k2n)
montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 -background '#ffffff' -fill 'gray' -auto-orient  -tile 8x6 -geometry 200x200+2+2 "${files[@]}" /media/
```

See:

- [Bash Builtin Commands § readarray](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray),
- [sort invocation (GNU coreutils)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html).

Comment: or with `xargs -0`

Comment: @Lea I couldn't find a way to insert multiple arguments in the middle of a command line with xargs. Can you post the full invocation?

Comment: `xargs -i'{}' -0 montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 -background '#ffffff' -fill 'gray' -auto-orient  -tile 8x6 -geometry 200x200+2+2 {} /media/`

Comment: @Lea That'll run montage n times for n files, OP wants to run it once for n files.

Comment: `xargs -i'{}' -0 -n $((2**63-1)) montage -verbose -label '%f' -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 -background '#ffffff' -fill 'gray' -auto-orient  -tile 8x6 -geometry 200x200+2+2 {} /media/`

Comment: @Lea seems a bit hacky to me, If you post it as an answer I'll upvote though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215094/discussion-between-lea-gris-and-oguz-ismail).

Answer (score 2):

A variant of [@oguz ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62131337/7939871) using `xargs` to stream the file-names arguments rather than a Bash array.

```sh
printf '%s\0' ./*.bluemap.jpg |
  sort -z -t/ -k2n |
    xargs -0 sh -c '
montage \
 -verbose \
 -label "%f" \
 -font "Helvetica" \
 -pointsize 10 \
 -background "#ffffff" \
 -fill "gray" \
 -auto-orient \
 -tile 8x6 \
 -geometry 200x200+2+2 \
 "$@" \
 /media/
' _
```

Split explanation of `xargs -0 sh -c`:

- `-0`: The entries in the input stream are delimited by `null`.
- `sh -c 'script' _`: The command executed by `xargs` is an inline shell script whith the arguments from the input stream.

Alternatively to an inline shell script:

```sh
{
  # Create the null-delimited list of input file names
  # matching the globbing pattern ./*.bluemap.jpg
  printf '%s\0' ./*.bluemap.jpg |
    # Sort the null delimited list of file names
    sort -z -t/ -k2n;
  # At this point, the null-delimited list contains the sorted input files
  # Append the `/media/` destination argument as last entry
  printf '/media/\0';
} | xargs -0 \
      montage \
        -verbose \
        -label "%f" \
        -font "Helvetica" \
        -pointsize 10 \
        -background "#ffffff" \
        -fill "gray" \
        -auto-orient \
        -tile 8x6 \
        -geometry 200x200+2+2
```

Comment: `xargs` does not work that way, it will not work. Either `-i{}` which means it substitutes `{}` for one argument. Or `-n<number>` which uses count of arguments. You can't mix them. As of now, your code ignores `-i{}` and runs `montage .... "{}" "/media/" <file1> <file2> ...`. [repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/FrightenedKlutzyScientists#main.sh). You can do `{ printf ... | sort ...; printf '/media/\0/'; } | xargs -0 montage` you can output the arguments that should be after the list with the stream.